# I tried to run this code it runs without throwing error and the question is to It doesn't execute for loopsI am just a beginner so please

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

Find the sum of all even integers between 2 and the input value ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialization and declaration of variable
    int input, sum = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Ask user to input data
    System.out.print("Enter a number you want to limit up-to : ");
    input = sc.nextInt();

    //Conditions
    if(input < 2) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred! Please, Enter a number greater or equal to 2. ");
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++ ) {
        if( i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute, if you never print a value?

Comment: By the way Rajesh, a small tip regarding your for loop... You don't have to increment `i` by only 1. You can increment it by any value or formula you want... `i += 2` for example in your case. Just saying, in case you'd like a small optimization for your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should print your result `sum`. Adding `System.out.println("the sum is:" + sum)` before the main method closed. Here is the complete code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialization and declaration of variable
        int input, sum = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask user to input data
        System.out.print("Enter a number you want to limit up-to : ");
        input = sc.nextInt();

        //Conditions
        if(input < 2) {
            System.out.println("Error Occurred! Please, Enter a number greater or equal to 2. ");
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
            if( i % 2 == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the sum is:" + sum);
    }
}
```

As the [Tim-Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12764490/tim-hunter) said, you could set the step of `i` is 2. Becasue if `i` is even, the `i+1` must be odd. Code like this:

```java
for (int i = 2; i <= input; i+=2) {
  if( i % 2 == 0) {
    sum += i;
  }
}
```

Comment: If they do the `i += 2` setup, they can also remove the modulus check since it will always have an even value.

Answer (score 0):

I am satisfied with all answers but why do it in linear time if you can do it in constant time, by using some math, by which you will not need loops at all.
but if you're just leaning loops , go with above answer.

if you know A.P then you can easy see you are finding the sum of an A.P

so your first term a = 2 as you said.

your common difference d = 2 as only even numbers.

last term l = input by user = a + (n-1)d;

so n = (l - a)d + 1.
and sum = n/2(a + l).

**Note** 
in code check whether or not user entering a odd number as input , because last term of an A.P with common difference 2 can't be odd, if user enter odd number you subtract one from it otherwise leave it,

it is simple as

`if(input % 2 == 0)
input -=1;`

`numberOfTerms = (input - 2 )/2 + 1;` //numberOfTerms is n;

`sum = (numberOfTerms(2 + input))/2;` // input is l;